# Perl: LWP::UserAgent returns always code 200 for redirected urls

Tags: perl, http, lwp-useragent

I have a simple url which does a 302 temp. move to another page.

I try to get to if the URL returns code 200 (for OK) to retrieve it and to stop if something else than 200 is returned.

My code:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( env_proxy => 1,keep_alive => 1, timeout => 30, agent => "Mozilla/4.76 [en] (Win98; U)");
my $response = $ua->get( $currenturl);
print $response->code;
```

The code above ALWAYS returns 200, even if its 302. I tested the header response using FireBug in Firefox. The URL returns "302 Moved Temporarily" in the Net module in FireBug. But the code above in perl returns 200. Why?

Comment: Try option max_redirect => 0. I guess that it returns code from last request.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

LWP::UserAgent automatically follows [HTTP redirects](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/libwww-perl/LWP/UserAgent.html#ua_gt_max_redirect).
You can disable such behavior by passing `max_redirect` option set to `0`.

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( max_redirect => 0, env_proxy => 1,keep_alive => 1, timeout => 30, agent => "Mozilla/4.76 [en] (Win98; U)");
my $response = $ua->get( $currenturl);
print $response->code;
```