# How to check 302 http response

Tags: perl

I'm trying to check the header of a redirection page, and get the 302 status,
but with my code I get the 200 OK status of the forwarded page. What should I do to get the redirection page 302 staus. My code:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $req = HTTP::Request->new('GET','http://host.com');
my $res = $ua->request($req);
print $res->status_line;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After initializing $ua, set its requests_redirectable property to undef:

```
$ua->requests_redirectable(undef);
```

That way LWP::UserAgent will not follow redirects and instead stop after the first request.

Then yoy can get the code( "302", "301", etc) using:

```
$res->code()
```

Here's the [official docs for LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.04/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm).

Comment: `$ua->max_redirect(0);` would be an alternative? [Or on constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8432612/4970442)?

Answer (score 4):

`$response->previous()` will be get you the previous response in the chain.

Or if you want to disable redirection, pass `requests_redirectable => []` to LWP::UserAgent's constructor.